# Fill a boxplot with 2 colors

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to fill a boxplot with 2 colors instead of 1 in `ggplot()`, using `geom_boxplot()`.

For example, there would be a first color between 0% and 80% of the boxplot width, and a second color between 80% and 100% of the boxplot width.

I could not find other example of such plots with geom_boxplot so I am not sure this is feasible.

I would like to avoid using `geom_rect()` or `annotate()`.

**Reproducible example**

```
##### Initiating objects
### Colors
colFill <- c("#4a7ff9", "#4aecf9")
colShader <- c("#4964a3", "#499ba2")

### Dataset
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(Values=rnorm(100, 100, 10), 
                 Group=rep(c("Blue", "Cyan"), each=50))

##### Display plot
ggplot(df, aes(y=Values, x=Group, fill=Group)) + 
  geom_boxplot(lwd=3, width=0.5) + 
  scale_fill_manual(values=colFill) + 
  theme_classic() + 
  theme(legend.position="none")
```

[image]

**My aim**

[image]

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a way to do it using only `geom_boxplot`. We use three layers: the first is main fill color only, with no lines. The second is a thin boxplot filled with the shading color, with no lines or outliers, nudged to the right. The third is a line-only boxplot. This avoids the need for using annotations or grob hacking.

```r
ggplot(df, aes(y = Values, x = Group, fill = Group)) + 
  geom_boxplot(lwd = 0, width = 0.5) + 
  geom_boxplot(position = position_nudge(0.2), width = 0.1,
               lwd = 0, aes(fill = paste(Group, 2)), outlier.shape = NA) +
  geom_boxplot(lwd = 3, width = 0.5, fill = NA) + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = c(colFill, colShader)[c(1, 3, 2, 4)], 
                    guide = 'none') + 
  theme_classic()
```

[image]

Comment: Would you describe my answer as grob hacking? Patterns are a feature of `ggplot2` now so arguably it is now the recommended approach. Having said that, I don't know how to do it without using `grid` and messing around with the width and height of the grobs, which very much felt like a hack. But drawing three box plots feels a bit similar. I wonder if there's a simpler way using patterns, like defining a gradient with two colours and only one break. But if there is I couldn't work it out...

Comment: @SamR no, I thought your answer was very useful. Perhaps one way to get the gradient fill with a sharp line is to have the colors replicated as a vector of four, like `c('lightblue', 'lightblue', 'navy', 'navy')`, and set the gradient breaks at `c(0, 0.799, 0.801, 1)`

Comment: Thank you, this is a nice idea! I just added the argument `, color=NA` in the second `geom_boxplot`, to hide the boxplot contour.

Comment: @AllanCameron thanks - that is exactly the way to do it. I've updated the answer. I don't think I completely understand why it has to be a vector of four for two colours, or why the break is at 0.799/0.801 rather than slightly before/after 0.75. Do you know how you would do it if you had to create a ratio of say, 6:1? I think with another example I should be able to understand the general principle.

Comment: @SamR the idea with the four colors is that between four colors you have three transitions. The 'gradient' between the first two colors occurs between 0 and 0.799, and because the colors are the same you get a single color between 0 and 0.799. Then, there's a rapid transition from the second to third color between 0.799 and 0.801 which is close enough to appear like an abrupt change. Finally, there is a 'transition' between 0.801 and 1 from the third to fourth colors which are the same. This method just allows control points at either end of the scale and on either side of the transition.

Comment: @SamR But the break could be before/after 0.75. My suggested breaks should make the transition occur at 80% of the width, which I thought the OP wanted. If you want a 6:1 ratio then `c(0, 6/7 - 0.001, 6/7 + 0.001, 1)` would do the trick.

Comment: @AllanCameron thanks! I was overcomplicating it - I understand now.

Answer (score 4):

This is a chance to play around with the patterns and gradients in [`ggplot 3.5.0`](https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2024/02/ggplot2-3-5-0/). Here are two approaches:

#### Using `grid::rectGrob()`

Create a function that returns a list of two `rectGrob` objects of different colors, which will act as the pattern:

```r
library(grid)
create_pattern <- function(color1, color2) {
    gList(
        rectGrob(
            x = 1, y = 1, width = 1, height = 2, hjust = 1,
            gp = gpar(fill = color1, col = NA)
        ),
        rectGrob(
            x = 1, y = 1, width = 0.25, height = 2, hjust = 1,
            gp = gpar(fill = color2, col = NA)
        )
    ) |>
        gTree(children = _) |>
        pattern()
}
```

Then we can create the patterns and draw the plot:

```r
patterns <- list(
    create_pattern(colFill[1], colShader[1]),
    create_pattern(colFill[2], colShader[2])
)

# or if you have more levels
# patterns <- Map(\(x, y) create_pattern(x, y), colFill, colShader, USE.NAMES = FALSE)

ggplot(df, aes(y = Values, x = Group, fill = Group)) +
    geom_boxplot(lwd = 3, width = 0.5) +
    scale_fill_manual(values = patterns) +
    theme_classic() +
    theme(legend.position = "none")
```

[image]

#### Using `grid::linearGradient()`

A more elegant solution using `linearGradient()`, suggested by Allan Cameron. Again we can create a function to produce the gradient:

```r
binary_gradient <- function(color1, color2, ratio = c(3, 1)) {
    linearGradient(
        c(color1, color1, color2, color2),
        stops = c(c(0, ratio[1] / sum(ratio), ratio[1] / sum(ratio), 1)),
        y1 = 1
    )
}
```

```r
patterns <- Map(
    binary_gradient,
    colFill,
    colShader,
    USE.NAMES = FALSE
)

ggplot(df, aes(y = Values, x = Group, fill = Group)) +
    geom_boxplot(lwd = 3, width = 0.5) +
    scale_fill_manual(values = patterns) +
    theme_classic() +
    theme(legend.position = "none")
# ^^ produces the same plot as above
```

Comment: @YacineHajji I don't know because I don't get that error - did you update your `ggplot2` to 3.5?

Comment: That sounds like your R version. What do you get if you run `packageVersion("ggplot2")`? If in doubt you should be able to upgrade with `install.packages("ggplot2")`.

Comment: You are right, I updated with 3.5. and it works perfectly!

Comment: Great. I think the approach using `linearGradient()` is better than using a grob. Shame I didn't come up with how to do it!